# Does Ripple require users to input their ID and personal data?

Tags: ripple, ripple-gateways

Currently all the USD to crypto currency exchanges require personal identification before withdrawing to USD. Does Ripple require this? How about the Ripple Gateways that do the currency conversions?

Comment: Ripple doesn't, but gateways can set whatever policies they want.

Comment: @NickODell That could be posted as an answer. It's a bit short but it's the correct answer... someone could expand on it if they want.

Comment: This is like asking if bitcoin requires users to input ID and personal data. Bitcoin has no concept of "withdrawing to USD" and neither does Ripple. In both cases you have to interact with a party that will give you USD (if that's what you want) in exchange for something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ripple has no such requirements, nor could it. It is designed to function without any central authorities. A Ripple account is created just by sending a small amount of XRP to it. The account's owner authenticates using a public/private key pair.

In principle, you could get USD into or out of Ripple without going through a gateway directly. You can meet someone in person anonymously, hand them a $50 bill, and they could give you a $50 Ripple balance. In reverse, you could sell a Ripple balance in person anonymously for cash. But in practice, to get money into and out of Ripple, you'll typically use a gateway's issue and redeem functions, and they will have identity policies.

Gateways can also require you to provide them identification just to hold balances from them on Ripple. To my knowledge, no gateway currently does this.